# Leaving my full time job for 1 client

Tags: contracts, attracting-clients, web-development, consulting, business-plan

About a year ago I tried to start a consulting company. approached potential clients with my services but did not get anywhere. I am now working full time and one of them has come back to me and would like to do business. Now, will it be wise to quit my full time job and focus on my business with this client?

Comment: I don't think **anyone** can answer this for you, we do not know your life situation. I will say, putting your livelihood in the hands of ONE client is often a mistake.

Comment: I agree with @Scott that we cannot evaluate what you should or can do. However, if the question is rephrased to something like 'Which factors should I consider when starting out on my own', it would be more useful. I have written an answer under that assumption.

Comment: You didn't inform in your post what the your kind of job you're *currently*currently doing. Is it *Web Development*?

Comment: @JorgeLuiz, not exacty. i am a QA automation specialist and in the business of software Quality Assurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, this will come down to your personal circumstances.

There are a few factors one generally needs to consider when going alone:

1. Your financial situation
2. The reliability of the first client (do they have enough work; will they pay)
3. How likely it is that you will be able to attract other clients
4. How your jurisdiction views self-employed people with only a single client

I agree with @Scott that depending on a single client is risky - but in my experience going alone rarely happens in the ideal way. At some time, push comes to shove - and one needs to take a leap of faith.

If your first client turns out to be solid, it could be a great platform for continued success - as finding that first client is often much harder than finding the second and third. However, beware of the potential 'pitfall of success' where you neglect pursuing other clients because things are great with the first one.

Answer (score 3):

The most of experienced freelancers always advise never abandoning your current job. If you wish to freelance only do it keeping your current one and working part-time as freelancer. At least it'd be ideal in the freelancer point of view. Think carefully to respect of that your current one would be, is actually your more secure foundation.

To freelance is a *highly risky* form of job due to following very important point in my humble opinion:

> **Customers**: they aren't constant, your one flow could change for more or
> less going to almost zero (*in the worst scenario*) at any moment.
> Freelancers get used to relate that can there are months on that can
> there is no any one (*here is where comes in the point which I related
> some lines above about your current job as your secure foundation*).*

The following article bellow could help you to reflect better about you issue:

> [Ask A Freelancer: Can I Quit My Full-Time Job and Freelance For My
> Employer?](https://contently.net/2015/01/28/voices/ask-freelancer/ask-freelancer-can-quit-full-time-job-freelance-employer/)

The article above has an *very important point* to be *carefully* thought of check it out on the following paragraph cited bellow:

> *You risk not having work or not having enough work. You risk underselling your services and earning less money than you should or
> overbidding and losing a project. You have nobody at your company to
> back you up if things go wrong with a client. You need to be willing
> to take those risks, learn from your mistakes, and always keep moving
> forward.*

Comment: Good input.  I am retired so I have a consistent, steady retirement income.  I just want to freelance or part-time contract for some extra income, to keep current with the technology should I need to go back to work and to keep busy.  With all this in mind, how would you approach freelance or part-time work?

Comment: [Making it in way as informal as possible. Try beginning to build your own blog and portfolio for marketing your services as freelancer. There are several articles on the internet teaching how to begin in right way.](https://www.codingdojo.com/blog/how-to-become-a-freelance-web-developer)